# HTML5/Javascript Placement of "+1" in Script for Numbers

Tags: javascript, html

I have a function that deals with numbers that the user enters. I have a variable "r" and variable "y". I have to incorporate r and y as exponents of each other and have another variable "total" for the total.

My question is this: how do I take whatever the user enters for var "r" and add 1 to it so that it is identified as "r+1" for the other variables interact.

here is the part of the code I'm talking about

```
var r=parseFloat (document.orderform.interest.value);
var y=parseFloat (document.orderform.loan.value);
var x=Math.pow(r,y);
var total= (r/1200) * (x) (y*12)
```

So basically I just want to take what the user enters in "r" and add 1 to it. I don't want to manually add it to the var total part because it needs to function in the "x" variable.

Comment: Uh `var r = parseFloat(document.orderform.interest.value) + 1;`

Comment: Did you make any effort at all to solve this ?

Comment: Thank you for your help. I didn't know how it worked and I didn't know if the script would recognize it if I typed it in like that, not to mention I'm still working on the script and I have way of knowing if it is working as intended yet. I made the question very simple so I didn't waste too much time of anyone's and decided to do the other parts myself.ef

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want? Or there is something I misunderstood?

```
var r=parseFloat (document.orderform.interest.value) + 1;
var y=parseFloat (document.orderform.loan.value);
var x=Math.pow(r,y);
var total= (r/1200) * (x) (y*12)
```

or

```
var r=parseFloat (document.orderform.interest.value);
var y=parseFloat (document.orderform.loan.value);
var x=Math.pow(r+1,y);
var total= (r/1200) * (x) (y*12)
```

Comment: You understood correctly. I'm not sure if I want to use the first or second code that you provided but I will test both of them out. Thank you